# Perl : Name "main::IN" used only once, but it is actually used

Tags: perl, autodie

I writing a short perl script that reads in a file. See `tmp.txt`:

```
1   gene_id "XLOC_000001";  gene_name "DDX11L1";    oId
1   gene_id "XLOC_000001";  gene_name "DDX11L1";    oId
1   gene_id "XLOC_000001";  gene_name "DDX11L1";    oId
1   gene_id "XLOC_000001";  gene_name "DDX11L1";    oId
```

My perl program, `convert.pl` is :

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;        # die if io problem with file
my $line;
my ($xloc, $gene, $ens);
open (IN, "tmp.txt")
    or die ("open 'tmp.txt' failed, $!\n");
while ($line = <IN>) {
    ($xloc, $gene) = ($line =~ /gene_id "([^"]+)".*gene_name "([^"]+)"/);
    print("$xloc   $gene\n");
}
close (IN)
    or warn $! ? "ERROR 1" : "ERROR 2";
```

It outputs:

```
 Name "main::IN" used only once: possible typo at ./convert.pl line 8.
 XLOC_000001   DDX11L1 
 XLOC_000001   DDX11L1 
 XLOC_000001   DDX11L1
 XLOC_000001   DDX11L1
```

I used `IN`, so I don't understand the `Name "main::IN" used...` warning.  Why is it complaining?

Comment: Use lexical variable and 3 arg open: `open my $IN, '<', 'tmp.txt or die ...`

Comment: `or die ...` is superfluous as you are using `autodie`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is mentioned under [**BUGS**](https://metacpan.org/pod/autodie#BUGS) section of autodie

> "Used only once" warnings can be generated when autodie or Fatal is used with package filehandles (eg, FILE). **Scalar filehandles are strongly recommended instead**.

---

`use diagnostics;` says:

> Name "main::IN" used only once: possible typo at test.pl line 9 (#1)
>   (W once) Typographical errors often show up as unique variable names. 
>   If you had a good reason for having a unique name, then just mention
>   it again somehow to suppress the message.  The our declaration is also
>   provided for this purpose.
>
> NOTE: This warning detects package symbols that have been used only
>   once.  **This means lexical variables will never trigger this warning**. 
>   It also means that all of the package variables $c, @c, %c, as well as
>   *c, &c, sub c{}, c(), and c (the filehandle or format) are considered the same; if a program uses $c only once but also uses any of the
>   others it will not trigger this warning. Symbols beginning with an
>   underscore and symbols using special identifiers (q.v. perldata) are
>   exempt from this warning.

So if you use lexical filehandle then it will not warn.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;        # die if io problem with file
use diagnostics;
my $line;
my ($xloc, $gene, $ens);
open (my $in, "<", "tmp.txt")
    or die ("open 'tmp.txt' failed, $!\n");
while ($line = <$in>) {
    ($xloc, $gene) = ($line =~ /gene_id "([^"]+)".*gene_name "([^"]+)"/);
    print("$xloc   $gene\n");
}
close ($in)
    or warn $! ? "ERROR 1" : "ERROR 2";
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is because of `autodie`.

I don't know exactly why, but if you remove it, it goes away.

If you read [`perldoc autodie`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Epjf/autodie-2.29/lib/autodie.pm) you'll see:

> BUGS ^
>
> "Used only once" warnings can be generated when autodie or Fatal is used with package filehandles (eg, FILE). Scalar filehandles are strongly recommended instead.

I'd suggest that's because of how the `or die` is being handled, compared to `autodie` trying to handle it.

However I'd also suggest it would be much better style to use a 3 argument `open`:

```
open ( my $input, '<', 'tmp.txt');
```

And *either* `autodie` or `or die`. I must confess, I'm not really sure which way around the two would be applied if your process did fail the `open`.